# soda.js Selenium RC 2 How to Reuse Browser Session

Tags: javascript, selenium, teamcity, mocha.js

I working with Soda.js, mocha and selenium RC. I'm trying to speed up my testing and one way I was thinking is since I'm starting a new session for each test (i.e. running through closing/opening an new browser and logging into a site).

I've seen numerious incomplete posts on various forums/message boards about reusing sessions for other languages but my tests are all Javascript.

Does anyone know how I can reuse the previous browser/session once I start my tests so I dont have to start a new session in each test.

My test runner for soda looks like this.

```
var soda = require('soda'),
util = require('util'),

//config object - values injected by TeamCity
config = {
    host: process.env['SELENIUM_HOST'] || 'localhost',
    port: process.env['SELENIUM_PORT'] || 4444,

   url: process.env['SELENIUM_SITE'] || 'http://google.com',      
    browser: process.env['SELENIUM_BROWSER'] || 'firefox'
};
```

describe("TEST_SITE", function(){

```
beforeEach(


    function(done){
    browser = soda.createOnPointClient(config);

    // Log commands as they are fired
        browser.on('command', function(cmd, args){
        console.log(' \x1b[33m%s\x1b[0m: %s', cmd, args.join(', '));
    });

    //establish the session
    browser.session(function(err){
        done(err);
    });

    }

);



afterEach(function(done){

    browser.testComplete(function(err) {
        console.log('done');
        if(err) throw err;
       done();
    });

});


describe("Areas",function(){
   var tests = require('./areas');
   for(var test in tests){
       if(tests.hasOwnProperty(test)){
           test = tests[test];
           if(typeof( test ) == 'function')
               test();
           else if (util.isArray(test)) {
               for(var i=0, l=test.length;i<l;i++){
                   if(typeof( test[i] ) == 'function')
                       test[i]();
               }
           }
       }

   }
});
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer. I really needed to be concentrating on mocha more for my answer which was along the lines of this:

```
    //before running the suite, create a connection to the Selenium server
before(
    function(done){
    browser = soda.createOnPointClient(config);

    // Log commands as they are fired
        browser.on('command', function(cmd, args){
        console.log(' \x1b[33m%s\x1b[0m: %s', cmd, args.join(', '));
    });

    //establish the session
    browser.session(function(err){
        done(err);
    });

    }
);

//after each test has completed, send the browser back to the main page (hopefully cleaning our environment)
afterEach(function(done){browser.open('/',function(){
    done();
});
});

//after the entire suite has completed, shut down the selenium connection
after(function(done){

    browser.testComplete(function(err) {
        console.log('done');
        if(err) throw err;
       done();
    });

});
```

The result so far was that I'm not seeing any real performance gain by reusing the session over starting a new one. My tests still take roughly the same amount of time.